# Angular 2 app on Apache server

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, angular

I have an angular 2 app served on Angular 2. On the host, it is located at the document root and everything is working fine. I have an .htaccess file with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]    
</IfModule>
```

Problem:
On my laptop, i have an Apache server (xampp) with document root as "
c:\users...\WebProjects

When i develop the site, i put the files in c:\users...\Projects\Projects1\dist
In this directory, i cannot get the website to work due to files/folders called not being in the root. ie Server is trying to load \css\app.css when it should be loading Projects1\dist\css\app.css

Can i write a specific .htaccess to be able to serve the app from that directory? (or something else without having to change the httpd.conf document root?)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the path in your .htaccess file and your index.html file like so:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /your/path/here/
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]    
</IfModule>
```

In index.html, you need to update the base href aswell to reflect the path like so:

`<base href="/your/path/here/">`

And that should do the trick :)